# Что означает запись "!0"

Tags: javascript

Увидел запись в чужом js коде, и наткнулся на такой синтаксис, который мне не понятен...

```
 e.prop("disabled", !0)
```

Что означает !0? Если это отрицание 0, то получится 1 - почему не написать просто 1?

Comment: Получится не 1, а true

Comment: @andreymal а что за запись такая, чем она лучше чем написать true?

Comment: Длиной на два символа меньше) Я тут никаких скрытых смыслов не вижу, и если их правда нет, то я категорически против такой записи, так как путает зазря

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это последствия минификации - минификаторы скриптов могут опционально экономить 2 символа на каждом `true`.